# Swift - Today Extension get width and height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I get the `width` and `height` of Today Extension programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Check the frame of the view in the **viewDidAppear** method

self.view.frame.width & self.view.frame.height would give you what you want.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewDidAppear(animated)
          let width = self.view.frame.width
          let height = self.view.frame.height
    }
```